# Installation of android sdk

Tags: android-2.2-froyo

I have eclipse and android sdk. I have tried to add through `Eclipse>Window>Install new software>Add>Local` and gave path of my android sdk location. but it shows an error: no repository found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay first that's the wrong place to configure the location of the SDK.  the "Install new software" window is for installing add-on's to eclipse only you don't configure anything from there. So the only thing related to android you'd be doing in there is installing or updating the ADT Plugin; Configuring it to find the SDK is a different area.  btw you do have to have the ADT plug in installed before the option to set the SDK path is available.

```
http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html 
How to Install the ADT in Eclipse
```

once you've done that then you go to

> Window > Preferences > Android

and that will give you the proper prompt and browse button to designate the path to the SDK